# jquery validation error

Tags: jquery, validation

```
$("#submit-signin-button").click(function() {
    if($.trim($("#foo").val()) === ""){
        $(".error-message-uname").show();
    }
    if($.trim($("#bar").val()) === ""){
        $(".error-message-bar").show();
    }

    return false;
```

Is it right way to do the validation? Because after submitting the correct form it does not post data to the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are always returning `false` from this. You should only return false when the form should not be posted.

A very basic validation system based on your revised question. You have a variable initially set to true (all is fine) unless an error has occurred. Returning `true` on a form validation will cause the form to submit.

```
$("#submit-signin-button").click(function() {

  var isValid = true;

  if(!$.trim($("#foo").val()){
    $(".error-message-uname").show();
    isValid = false;
  }
  if(!$.trim($("#bar").val())){
    $(".error-message-bar").show();
    isValid = false;
  }

  return isValid;
}
```

For simple things, this is perfectly fine but there are some validation jQuery plugins ([like this one](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation)) that you could use.

As a tip (so you know), an empty string is considered a `falsey` value in JavaScript. So you can replace `$.trim($("#bar").val() === ""` with `!$.trim($("#bar").val()`.

Comment: what about if have another field to validate. I have update the question.